# HTML 'moving link over' div span, nbsp

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey,
How do I move my link over to the side? It's probably something really dumb:)

The link sits on top of my image. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .plus{left:0px;height:17px;width:17px; background:url('sprit.gif') 0 0px;}
    .minus{left:0px;height:17px;width:17px; background:url('sprit.gif') 0 -17px;}
    #container {background-image: url(body.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;margin: 0px auto; max-width:700px;}
    #bump{padding-right:55px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <!--LINK IS NOT MOVING-->
        <div id="deToggle"><div id="bunp">&nbsp;</div><span><a href="#">Larger</a></span></div>
            <!--SCRIPT HERE-->
            <script language="javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){ 
                     Plus();
                     $('#deToggle').toggle(function(){
                        Plus();
                     }, function(){
                     });
                });
                function Plus(){
                    var tog = $('#deToggle');
                    tog.addClass('plus');
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `#bump{` and `<div id="bunp">` ... fix your typo.

Comment: That typo was half of my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this in your css
a {padding:0em 0em 0em 10em;}

You may consider also moving it just outside of the div the image is in.